# Processing: FATAL EXCEPTION: Animation Thread java.lang.OutOfMemoryError (Android mode)

Tags: android, processing, frames

I am running an android app on my device using processing. But I get this error:

```
      FATAL EXCEPTION: Animation Thread
      java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:592)
      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:691)
      at processing.core.PApplet.loadImage(Unknown Source)
          at processing.test.djtubedesktop.DJTubeDesktop.loadImages(DJTubeDesktop.java:972)
      at processing.test.djtubedesktop.DJTubeDesktop.setup(DJTubeDesktop.java:62)
      at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(Unknown Source)
      at processing.core.PGraphicsAndroid2D.requestDraw(Unknown Source)
      at processing.core.PApplet.run(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I have tried this:
1) Going to File -> preferences, and select "then Increase maximun available memory to" 10240 MB
2) Reducing the number of frames.
   I have this 2 code lines:

```
       images = loadImages("Animation_data/movie", ".jpg", 134);
       recordPlayer = loadImages("black-record_", ".png", 36);
```

I have replaced 134 and 36 for 50 and 10, and by doing this I dont get the error, but it still does not work

The programs runs perfectly on java

I need to run it on my android device

Answer (score 1):

The image you are manipulating is too large for Android. You are running out of Bitmap memory Try making the image smaller. You might want to check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html) link.

Answer (score 0):

OutOfmemory Exception :-

this is because the image size is heavy.try using this code.

```
Bitmap bitmapimagesize = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(your bitmap,
                        yourbitmap.getWidth() / 5, yourbitmap.getHeight() / 5,
                        false);
```

or this:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 5;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_path, options);
```